# NetworkX MultiDiGraph -- `id` and `key` appearing in edge data attributes?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, digraphs

I'm iterating over edges in a NetworkX MultiDiGraph like so:

```
for u, v, k, d in g.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    ...
```

In some instances, I find `id` and `key` keys in the dictionary `d`, but I can't figure out when or why these are created, except that it only happens when `u==v`.

I have been unable to find a minimal example of what causes this. It seems strange to me that the key `k` would be duplicated in the attr dict `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this has been solved, I was using `nx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_graph()` to read/write my graphs from JSON. I think it was this step that was adding the `id` and `key` values to the edge attr_dict.

However, I don't know if this is a bug when reading from JSON, or if this is working as intended.